# Secure my network by subnetting?

Tags: networking, security, subnet

So I play around with home servers a good bit (mostly for learning purposes). The problem is that I do all of this on my home network, While I tend to never open ports on my router and keep everything in my LAN, for some things I would like to have the router ports opened. Seeing as I'm no expert, I'm looking for a safer way for me to do these things.

Bellow is an image of what im thinking of doing. Basically subletting the network, but i don't know how safe this would be. I'm open to any new ideas also:

[image: Network Idea]

I'm not the only one on this network, my wife and kids use it too. I don't want to open a port for a service and have my whole network compromised.
If y'all have any other solutions for this problem I'm opened to hear it, thank you!

EDIT: The modem I have is the standard one provided by my ISP. It has a ethernet connection and a DSL connection, nothing else. The switch I will be placing would be the netgear prosafe GS108T. This switch is managed and it does support VLANs.

The switch has:
IEEE 802.1Q Static VLAN
(64 groups, Static)

My modem is a ARRIS CM820A.

Comment: Your initial switch will not work hw you expect unless your modem can VLAN. You should use a router that can VLAN. This will give you the separation you desire whilst offering the best security. Look at the likes of OpenWRT/Tomato/etc. if budget is tight, or look at a decent business-grade router. I tend to play about a lot with DrayTek - which you can pick up fairly cheaply off eBay. these can VLAN and have multiple functions like different DHCP servers, inter-LAN communication etc. etc.

Comment: @Kinnectus: I think OP just put the "network 1/2" labels in the wrong place. In this diagram, they only make sense below the router, not above.

Comment: @grawity, either way they've got what can only be assumed as a dumb switch infront of two routers and behind a modem... for them to be able to do the diagram they're going to need the kit that can achieve it.... or have I missed something :S - If the modem is a modem/router (a typical home ISP) then this could potentially work but they'd still need some VLAN capability or a smart switch with DHCP helper etc etc to be able to route the different subnets. The simple solution is a router that can do all this in one unit. Either by means of port based VLANs or virtual interfaces...

Comment: well the modem is provided by my isp... all it has is 1 ethernet(internet) port and a dsl cable port. the switch i plan on using is the netgear proSAFE, it is a managed switch and it provides VLAN

Comment: @Kinnectus: Assuming the modem is just a modem – _might be_ doable as long as the ISP gives a separate public address to every device. (Some ISPs do, most don't.) If the modem is in fact a 3rd router – quite doable because the modem/router will just give internal addresses to the 1st/2nd routers.

Comment: @Raden: It could still be just an ADSL modem, or it could be a modem/router, regardless of port count. (Check if it's a router, and if it's a router, whether it has VLAN support.) What other hardware (the 1st/2nd routers themselves) are you planning on using? Do _they_ support VLANs (at least one of them)?

Comment: ok Im not shure if my modem works as a router or not, but I connected my pc directly to it. I did a network scan and it looks like i'm picking up every other router in my neighborhood, It picked up around 50 other devices. they all seem to be connected to to another router? I did the scan using wireless network watcher

Comment: The problem is that your modem exposes a single, public IP from your ISP. To be able to have multiple devices use this IP you must have a router so that it can translate requests from LAN IPs to the single WAN IP (NAT). You can't simply connect two routers to a single IP because there's nothing routing the single IP to the "WAN" IPs of the two routers (they need to be different to ensure traffic is correctly routed to them). If you connected both to the modem then you'd need to give them both the same public IP - this doesn't work (unless your ISP gives you more than one public IP).

Comment: If you use the likes of a cheap router with, say, DD-WRT, then you can create this required router between your modem and the switch. You can then create two VLANs on the switch and create a trunk port so that the VLANs can work with DD-WRT router to provide the NAT/separation you're looking for. Or, you could buy a business-grade device that can work with your Netgear switch (VLANs) and you could, essentially, replace the functionality you have in your diagram of the two routers for each subnet. this brings the complexity of your network down to two devices.

Comment: E.g. https://www.draytek.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/vlan-groups-1024x612.png - You can create the very same functionality with the likes of DD-WRT.... you don't *need* an expensive piece of kit.

Comment: ok i'm looking for some business grade routers. I'm not exactly sure witch one would server my purpose. Would something like the Linksys Business Dual WAN Gigabit VPN Router (LRT224) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. The people commenting on your orgional question are correct; You cannot put a layer 2 switch in front of a modem. Your ISP almost certainly will not allow multiple routers to be connected 'directly' to the modem. They will not give you 2 IP addresses, so you must put a router, a layer 3 device, here to share 1 IP address with two networks.

The router immediately behind your modem will run two networks: A Demilitarized Zone (DMZ - your public facing network) and a private internal network. The router will handle NAT Masquerading for both networks to obtain internet, and you will forward ports through to services only on your DMZ. You can put very specific firewall rules in for any traffic that needs to travel between the DMZ and the internal network, such as SSH for specific machines.

A commercial type router is preferred to do this. The [Ubiquiti Edge Router X](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/) is a popular choice among pro-sumers coming in at around $50. If you have a spare computer lying around, pfsense is also a viable option. I do not recommend replacing firmware on consumer routers as these routers have a hardware limitation; the LAN ports are permanently on the same LAN and VLAN may not be supported in hardware. These routers are designed only for single network usage. Ergo, best case your network will slow down due to CPU routing, worst case your VLAN isolation won't work because the hardware doesn't enforce it and you'll have no security. ER-X and pfSense both have Wizards for a 2 LAN configuration and many resources online for customizing the configuration to your specific needs. See what you prefer and post more questions if you have any.

Comment: There are also many consumer routers where WAN/LAN ports can be individually assigned to VLANs (because the SoC has only a single LAN port, and 1x WAN + 4x LAN are mapped by VLAN to this single LAN port, so VLAN capability is a given). Open Firmware like OpenWRT [makes it easy](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/vlan/switch_configuration) to configure them.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what kind of security you want to reach. On the schema you had posted there is a picture only. You did not wrote what IP address you get from ISP (public/private, fix/dhcp), what other services does provide ISP for you (proxy, dns, smtp/pop/imap, MX). What kind of OS do use your PC/servers. Do you want run your own dhcp, mail, web, file, dns or another server?

You cannot forget, that security does not mean: "no open port", as the many disasters came form behaviour of the client PC (opening fake e-mail, malware on a web page, etc.).

Well, my situation is very similar: ISP (giving dhcp public IPv4 address) <-> modem <-> intelligent linux based router/switch/proxy/cachingDNS/ntp <-> home-PCs running linux, and if my doughter want to play a MS-Windows driven game she uses KVM-Qemu virtualised PC runnig its virtual HD in snapshot mode. Hence even she can catch a virus, by restarting the virtual machine the system is back in a fresh state. I can start any reasonable public server occasionally, either on the linux gate, either on any home machine giving it the port forwarding or reverse proxy. For more then 15 years I have gotten no serious problem (yes, harddisk faild), originaly started with one core AMD Athlon64 machine as the linux gate, about two years ago I migrated to BananaPi router (a fork of RasberyPi).

An other important part of security is, of course, the regular back-up. It is highly recommended to save all running system disk as a disk image, and carry out a data backup with reasonable regularity.

Linux, what else.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing a lot of research and learning I understand what you guys mean. So I got me a USED Dell Optiplex 3020 SFF and Intel PRO 1000 PT Quad Port 1Gb PCI Ethernet Network Adapter NIC. I will be setting up the dell as a pfsense firewall and use that to manage my network and set up my vlans.